# Login to PostgreSQL - Login failed

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, phppgadmin

I installed psql and phpPgAdmin to my Ubuntu11.10 and don't know how to run it. What is the default username and password?

Answer (score 53):

There is no default username and password without you creating one. The simplest possible setup is to follow these steps to set up your own user as a superuser.

At a terminal prompt, create a postgres user with your own username

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
```

Start the postgresql command prompt as your username but running as root since you didn't set a password yet;

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

At the postgresql prompt, set your password;

```
\password $USER
```

After that, you should be able to log on just fine.

The setup is more thoroughly documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).

**EDIT:**

If you get stuck not being able to authenticate automatically as the `postgres` user, you may want to compare your `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf` (ie authentication config file) with the following lines from mine that works; you can get the uncommented ones using

```
grep -v ^# pg_hba.conf
```

The "local" lines should be the essential ones in this case since you can't authenticate even from the same machine;

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: $sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser $USER
Password: 
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: @IvanZ.Horvat Very odd, by default in Ubuntu, Postgresql is configured to use 'ident sameuser' authentication for any connections from the same machine, which means you should not have to use a password once you're logged in as that user in the OS. Just verified using my Ubuntu 11.10 that I can just log in like that on a fresh install.

Comment: @IvanZ.Horvat Added some info on hba.conf (the authentication configuration file) to my answer.

Comment: I'm getting: sudo: unknown user: postgres. I installed Postgres with Postgres.app for OS X.

Answer (score 4):

During the installation process you've probably missed steps:

> Now we need to reset the password for the ‘postgres’ admin account for the server, so we can use this for all of the system administration tasks. Type the following at the command-line (substitute in the password you want to use for your administrator account):

```
sudo su postgres -c psql template1
template1=# ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'password';
template1=# \q
```

> That alters the password for within the database, now we need to do the same for the unix user ‘postgres’:

```
sudo passwd -d postgres
sudo su postgres -c passwd
```

> Now enter the same password that you used previously.

http://hocuspokus.net/2008/05/install-postgresql-on-ubuntu-804/

Comment: ivan@ivan-Inspiron-N5110:~$ sudo su postgres -c psql template1
[sudo] password for ivan: 
Password:

Comment: psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Answer (score 4):

There is a good article by digital ocean [here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Key point:
Without creating another user,access postgres as the default account named 'postgres'

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
```

One can always exit using \q